# What is the recommended goodness of fit test for binary logistic regression with large sample size?

Tags: logistic, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, roc, accuracy

I have a binary logistic regression with one unique independent variable X and several control variables. My data has over 240k observations. When I ran both HL and Pearson chi square goodness of fit test on stata, the p values were both 0.000, suggesting a poor fit of the model. But the classification test suggests accuracy is 81.4% and ROC is 75.14% (CI : 0.749 0.7538). Is there a problem with my model as goodness of fit tests were rejected? How can I fix this issue? I have read that HL test is not valid for large sample. Is it the same case for pearson goodness of fit test as well?

Comment: Neither of those measures have anything to do with goodness of fit, and the "accuracy" measure is not appropriate for logistic regression which is not a classification method.  Goodness of fit can be assessed using directed tests such as tests of linearity and additivity (no interaction).  Details may be found [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc).  Note that the HL test is not recommended for any sample size.